# Among the 2 codes is there a time complexity difference or faster by some constant factor?

Tags: c++, time-complexity

I have these 2 codes for a problem 'PRTAGN' on codechef. The first one is mine and is giving a time limit error. I saw a successful submission and was not able to tell why it is much faster. My code gave TLE at over 1 sec while the second code ran on every test case in less than 0.1 sec. I need help understanding why one code is much faster than the other.

I went through multiple correct answers to the question. They all seemed similar to my own code yet were much faster.

My code :

```
#include<set>
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;
unsigned int count1s(unsigned int n) {
    unsigned int count = 0;
    while (n) {
        count += n & 1;
        n >>= 1;
    }
    return count;
}
int main() {
    int ii,even,odd,ct,x,xor1;
    cin>>ii;
    set <int> arrodd,arreven;
    int arr[131072];
    for (int iii=0; iii<ii; iii++) {
        arreven.clear();arrodd.clear();
        for (int r=0;r<131072;r++){
            arr[r]=0;
        }
        even=0;
        odd=0;
        cin>>ct;
        for(int qq=0; qq<ct; qq++) {
            cin>>x;
            if (arr[x]==0) { // x not in set


                int no = count1s(x);
                if (no%2==0){
                    arr[x]=1;even++;
                    arreven.insert(x);
                }

                else{
                    odd++;arr[x]=2;arrodd.insert(x);
                }
            }
            set<int>::iterator it = arrodd.begin();

            while (it != arrodd.end()) {
                // Iterating over set
                int val = (*it);
                if (val!=x) {
                    xor1 = (val)^x;
                    if (arr[xor1]==0) { // x not in set
                        if (arr[x]==2){  // x is odd
                            even++;arr[xor1]=1;arreven.insert(xor1);
                        }
                        else{
                            odd++;arr[xor1]=2;arrodd.insert(xor1);
                        }
                    }

                }
                it++;
            }

            set<int>::iterator it2 = arreven.begin();

            while (it2 != arreven.end()) {
                // Iterating over set
                int val = (*it2);
                if (val!=x) {
                    xor1 = (val)^x;
                    if (arr[xor1]==0) { // x not in set
                        if (arr[x]==1){  // x is even
                            even++;arr[xor1]=1;arreven.insert(xor1);
                        }
                        else{
                            odd++;arr[xor1]=2;arrodd.insert(xor1);
                        }
                    }

                }
                it2++;
            }


            cout<<even<<" "<<odd<<endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The correct answer code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>
using namespace std;

unsigned int T, Q, X;

bool find_odd(unsigned int n) { 
    unsigned int count = 0; 
    while (n) { 
        count += n & 1; 
        n >>= 1; 
    } 
    return count % 2; 
} 

void solve() {
    vector<bool> vec(1e7, true);
    vec[0] = 1;
    vector<int> odd_seen;
    vector<int> even_seen;
    bool is_odd;
    int odd_size = 0;
    int even_size = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Q; ++i) {
        cin >> X;
        if (vec[X]) {
            vec[X] = false;
            is_odd = find_odd(X);
            odd_size = odd_seen.size();
            even_size = even_seen.size();

            for (int j = 0; j < even_size; ++j) {
                if (vec[even_seen[j]^X]) {
                    vec[even_seen[j]^X] = false;
                    if (is_odd) { 
                        odd_seen.push_back(even_seen[j]^X); 
                    } else  { 
                        even_seen.push_back(even_seen[j]^X);
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < odd_size; ++j) {
                if (vec[odd_seen[j]^X]) {
                    vec[odd_seen[j]^X] = false;
                    if (!is_odd) { 
                        odd_seen.push_back(odd_seen[j]^X); 
                    } else  { 
                        even_seen.push_back(odd_seen[j]^X); 
                    }
                }
            }
            if (is_odd) {
                odd_seen.push_back(X);
            } else {
                even_seen.push_back(X);
            }
        }
        cout << even_seen.size() << " " << odd_seen.size() << "\n";

    }

}

int main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);cin.tie(0);cout.tie(0);
    cin >> T;
    for (int t = 0; t < T; ++t) {
        cin >> Q;
        solve();
    }
}
```

Comment: Profile your code: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools